# How do names in the dircolors database map to those in LS_COLORS?

Tags: ls, documentation, coreutils

From `dircolors -p`, some types seem to have names:

```
#NORMAL 00 # no color code at all
#FILE 00 # regular file: use no color at all
RESET 0 # reset to "normal" color
DIR 01;34 # directory
LINK 01;36 # symbolic link. (If you set this to 'target' instead of a
 # numerical value, the color is as for the file pointed to.)
MULTIHARDLINK 00 # regular file with more than one link
FIFO 40;33 # pipe
SOCK 01;35 # socket
DOOR 01;35 # door
BLK 40;33;01 # block device driver
CHR 40;33;01 # character device driver
ORPHAN 40;31;01 # symlink to nonexistent file, or non-stat'able file ...
MISSING 00 # ... and the files they point to
SETUID 37;41 # file that is setuid (u+s)
SETGID 30;43 # file that is setgid (g+s)
CAPABILITY 30;41 # file with capability
STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE 30;42 # dir that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
OTHER_WRITABLE 34;42 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
STICKY 37;44 # dir with the sticky bit set (+t) and not other-writable
# This is for files with execute permission:
EXEC 01;32
```

How do these terms map to the terms used in `LS_COLORS`? `dircolors -p` has `OTHER_WRITABLE`, `LS_COLORS` seems to like `ow`; `dircolors -p` has `CHR`, which seems to be `cd` in `LS_COLORS`, and so on.

There's no explanation in [`man dircolors`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dircolors.1.html), or in [the GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#dircolors-invocation). Is this documented elsewhere?

---

```
$ dircolors --version
dircolors (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by H. Peter Anvin.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user is supposed to use the command [`dircolors`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/dircolors.1.html) to set `LS_COLORS`. The correspondence between the entries in a `dircolors` [configuration file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/dir_colors.5.html) file and the value of `LS_COLORS` environment variable is not documented and should not be relied upon.